# How to show a message on the cart after WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($cart_item_key) - Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I'm trying to check with my ERP if a product is in stock. So when you clic add to cart, I run a code checks if is in stock and then remove it if is out of stock. I want to show a message that said the product was remove cause outstock.

```
   function custom_validate_stock() {
       if(1==1){
           $stockERP = 0;
           if($stockERP < 1){
               if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
                   foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                       $_product = $values['data'];
                       if ( $_product->id == $product->id ){
                           WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($cart_item_key);
                           $removed = true;
                           break;
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
           if($removed){
               remove_action( 'woocommerce_cart_is_empty', 'wc_empty_cart_message', 10 );
               add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_is_empty', 'custom_empty_cart_message', 10 );
       
               
           }
       }
   }

   function custom_empty_cart_message() {
       $html  = '<div class="col-12 offset-md-1 col-md-10"><p class="cart-empty">';
       $html .= wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'wc_empty_cart_message', __( 'Your product is out of stock, please refresh the page.', 'woocommerce' ) ) );
       echo $html . '</p></div>';
   }
```

Comment: Why don't you validate before adding to the cart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right after

```
WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($cart_item_key);
```

I think you could add a notice:

```
wc_add_notice( __( 'Thing removed.', 'your-textdomain' ), 'error' );
```

Comment: Thank you very much @helgatheviking, it works. But the message is displayed on the product side and not on the cart side. Is it possible to show it also on the side of the cart? https://prnt.sc/u3kdi6

Comment: What do you mean by "product side" and "cart side"? Notices are added at the time they occur and then displayed the next time the page is loaded.